# Log output Base64 image string

Tags: android

Anyone knows how to Log output `Base64 encoded string`, following code doesn't output the full string.

```
Log.d("My Activity", encodeToBase64(bitmap, tmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100));
```

I'm trying to get this string copied to my clipboard and paste it to any online converter to see the image for testing, and it seems that `Log` is not the best way of achieving that

I tried `System.output.*` and it works fine but it gets interrupted with other printing to the console. and also print on separate lines

Comment: I think the max for Log is (4*1024) bytes, Another alternative is to create a file and print it from there.

Comment: create a file on the device you mean? @Rod_Algonquin

Comment: Yes, and you can then send VIA email  to yourself for easy access rather opening it in your phone.